# Integrate solana wallet adapter react ui in angular project

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, typescript

i am still new to solana developpement and i found solana/wallet adapter react ui and i was wondering if there is a tool or documentation on how to implement it on my angular appilication ?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some resources that may be helpful for setting up wallet-adapter with angular:

https://github.com/heavy-duty/wallet-adapter

https://github.com/danmt/wallet-adapter-angular-sample